# Task is canceled randomly on Linux Server

Tags: c#, linux, task, background-process, cancellation

I ran into the following problem: I start a task to process responses from a bot in a telegram for a long execution

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => _.RunAsync(), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning)
```

_ - is an instance of my service

method code below:

```
/// <inheritdoc />
    public async Task RunAsync()
    {
        // запуск метода рассылки пользователям сообщений со стоимостями их портфелей
        await _notifier.RunAsync(_cancellationTokenSource.Token);

        var updateReceiver = _telegramClient.GetUpdateReceiver(
            new[]
            {
                UpdateType.Message,
                UpdateType.CallbackQuery,
            });

        try
        {
            Logger.Info("Revaluate portfolios service successfully launched!");

            await foreach (var update in updateReceiver.WithCancellation(_cancellationTokenSource.Token))
            {
                var updateModel = new UpdateModel()
                {
                    Text = update.Message?.Text ?? update.CallbackQuery?.Data,
                    ChatId = update.Message?.Chat.Id ?? update.CallbackQuery?.Message?.Chat.Id ?? 0,
                    Phone = update.Message?.Contact?.PhoneNumber ?? "",
                    From = update.Message?.From ?? update.CallbackQuery?.From
                };

                await HandleMessageAsync(updateModel);
            }
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException exception)
        {
            Logger.Error(exception, "The service was stopped by token cancellation. Reason: ");
            throw;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Error(ex);
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            Dispose();
        }
    }
```

I assume that the error is called from a method `await HandleMessageAsync(updateModel);`
where I used `_cancellationTokenSource.Token`.

I received next error on my server (Ubuntu 2G RAM, 2 Core, 40G SSD):

`RevaluatePortfoliosService|The service was stopped by token cancellation. Reason:  System.OperationCanceledException: The operation was canceled`

But nothing could cause the cancellation. I don't understand why this is happening

Comment: There might be a hint here: http://blog.i3arnon.com/2015/07/02/task-run-long-running/

Comment: Try adding a callback : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/cancellation-in-managed-threads?force_isolation=true